# How non-abelian group of order pq looks like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Question: if $G$ is non-abelian group of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes such that, $p<q$ and $p$ **does not** divides $q-1$ then, is $G$ is unique? If yes then, how it's looks?

My attempt:  yes, $G$ must be unique and, it is nothing but, $\mathbb{Z}_q⋊ \mathbb{Z}_p $ that is, semi direct product of  $\mathbb{Z}_q$ and  $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
**Is am I right?**

But I didn't know how to prove this semidirect product is unique. Please help me.

Comment: Sir, it's not "exact" dublicate.

Comment: I need to prove the "uniqueness" of group G here.